# How center a title in PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I would like to know if there is an effective way to center the title into the form, I put `mtitle.move` but it's not easy to find the center by trial and error. If anybody can help me I'll appreciate that.

```
mtitle = QtGui.QLabel('GB DATABASE', self)
mtitle.setStyleSheet("font: bold 50pt AGENTORANGE") 
mtitle.resize(720, 80)
mtitle.move(200, 10)
```

Comment: You're trying to center the label in the window, or the text in the label? Also, maybe [setAlignment](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qlabel.html#alignment-prop) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from PyQt import QtCore
mtitle.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

(Note: Centering the Label-Widget inside it's parent widget can be done using QT's Layouts (standard method) or using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719337/centre-widget-on-parent-widget-without-layout)

Comment: Isn't that what's questioner wants to do?